# Selenium: how to check if context menu has appeared

Tags: python, selenium, contextmenu

I'm just starting with Selenium in python, and I have set up an ActionChains object and perform()ed a context click. How do I tell whether a context menu of any sort has actually popped up? For example, can I use the return value in some way?

The reason is that I want to disable the context menu in some cases, and want to test if this has actually been done.

Comment: Does your site capture the right click event and alters the response or are you just looking for the standard browser menu?

Comment: I'm just looking for the standard menu. Or indeed any menu. I want to check that one *doesn't* pop up if I have disabled context clicking in javascript.

Comment: You can call `.context_click()` and select an option, e.g. `refresh` and check whether page was really refreshed or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium cannot see or interact with native context menus.

I recommend testing this in a JavaScript unit test, where you can assert that `event.preventDefault()` was called. It's arguably too simple/minor of a behavior to justify the expense of a Selenium test anyway.